# GitHub Commits review

Tags: git, github, scrum

We are almost 7 developers in the project. When selecting the review, each team member must currently be entered manually. It would be nice if a group could be selected here. I created teams in Github. These are not found in the selection. Does somebody has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team has to be under the same organisation as the repository to be able to be requested for review.

Check [this](https://github.blog/2017-06-28-requesting-reviews-from-repository-teams/) out and [more about teams](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-teams)